# Angularjs - save defaulf date on a table?

Tags: c#, html, angularjs

**html**

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ModifiedDate" id="ModifiedDate">
```

**app.js**

```
  $scope.ModifiedDate = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

**model**

```
   public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
```

**controller**

```
     public IHttpActionResult PostPerson1(UserVM vm)
    {
        var pers = new Person1
        {

            Title = vm.Title,
            FirstName = vm.FirstName,
            LastName = vm.LastName,
            UserName = vm.UserName,
            EmailPromotion = vm.EmailPromotion,

            SMSPromotion = vm.SMSPromotion,
            Telephone = vm.Telephone,
            Extension = vm.Extension,
            Mobile = vm.Mobile,
            Email = vm.Email,
            Email2 = vm.Email2,
            ModifiedDate = (DateTime) vm.ModifiedDate,
            UserAuthRoleId = vm.UserAuthRoleId
        };

        var word = new Password();
        using (var context = new VybeEstoreEntities1())
        {

            context.People1.Add(pers);

           // word.PersonID = pers.PersonID;              
            word.ModifiedDate = pers.ModifiedDate;
            word.Password1 = vm.Password1;
            word.rowguid = vm.rowguid;
            context.Passwords.Add(word);

            context.SaveChanges();
```

i find an error on my C# code when i want to save a default date any help please.

error:

> {"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: If you debug before the save, what is the value of `ModifiedDate`? My guess is `DateTime.MinValue`?

Comment: @mattytommo what do mean debug before the save?

Comment: Debug in Visual Studio, put a breakpoint before the `db.SaveChanges` line and inspect the watch window to see what the value of `person1.ModifiedDate` is

Comment: i did that and its 01-jan-01

Comment: ModifiedDate = {01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: That's `DateTime.MinValue` (full value is 01/01/0001). Which means that your date value isn't getting posted back to the server (due to it being in an invalid format).

Comment: @mattytommo so how can i solve that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69602/discussion-between-ninjaxnado-and-mattytommo).

Comment: have you got your answer?

Comment: @micronyks no not yet im still strugling

Comment: Oh i'd like to see what you are getting in person1 when you make call from angularjs?

Comment: this is what i get from person1 ModifiedDate = {01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: @micronyks i still have a challenge on this error

Comment: Here you go. you have to convert this date into date format before sending it to server. as i said, I'd like to see what you are getting person1 object?

Comment: @micronyks look up to see what i get, unless that is what you dont want

Comment: How can i resolve this without looking at any data?

Comment: @micronyks  
this is what i get from person1 ModifiedDate = {01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: In controller.cs try to go with current date time without using your model value. if current dateTime is working properly (without any error) then there is some problem in your dateTime format.

Comment: is there only one filed/property in person1 object?

Comment: @micronyks no too many

Comment: @micronyks yes current datetime is working properly my problem is when i'm saving the current date to database.

Comment: then go with yyyy-mm-dd format. it will work i hope.

Comment: this what i get on my error :{"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: okay. convert you model's modified value to DataTime value in C#. typeCast.

Comment: You have to typecast it to DateTime and then try to insert it to DB. it will surely work.

Comment: i tried  ModifiedDate = (DateTime) vm.ModifiedDate, still gives me the same error

Comment: what is vm? please provide whole code.

Comment: its my variable for viewmodel

Comment: please on my updated code

Comment: you are trying to add person1 type of object intto people1 type of object. I think this is the problem area.

Comment: people1 and person1 are the same tables meaning its one table

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect your request (with fiddler or just the network tab in your favorite browser to see what data is posted). That said, it looks like, in your HTML, your input element is missing the `name` attribute. You should add that:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ModifiedDate"
id="ModifiedDate" name="ModifiedDate">
```

Your action method takes a Person1 as parameter. It needs a property called ModifiedDate for MVC to parse the ModifiedDate sent in the request. The ModifiedDate sent is formatted (by you!) with the format dd-MM-yyyy. Depending on the locale/cultureinfo in your asp.net application this format might be wrongly parsed as MM-dd-yyyy. You can test by setting the date to something that can be parsed even if day and months are swapped. You could try 10-10-2015 and see if that works. If this is the case you could try setting your CurrentCultureInfo to whatever cultureinfo you wish that accepts dd-MM-yyyy. Probably a european culture info.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK"); // Danish
```

There are more elegant ways of setting the current culture but seems like you're debugging right now...

Comment: still even if i added name its not saving to my database.

Comment: this what i get on my error :{"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: Can you inspect your request with the network tab? I suggest using chrome or firefox. In your request, do you see the ModifiedDate? Add a breakpoint in your controller and inspect your person1 - is the ModifiedDate set on that object? Perhaps mvc's modelbinder can not parse your ModifiedDate - your format might be wrong.

Comment: this is what i get from person1 ModifiedDate = {01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM} when i insert breakpoint

Comment: yes i do see the current date on ma text box my problem starts when saving

Comment: No your problem is that your ModifiedDate is never set on your person1 on your c# side. I'm trying to figure out if it is being sent as part of the request or not. If it IS being set, then the parsing by the mvc modelbinder is messing up. A common problem is the culture not matching the dateformat.